# How do fix the "missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'" error?

Tags: python, typeerror

I did some googling but still can't seem to find a way to solve this error. I have tried just changing the variables but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong and what should I do differently?

TypeError: get_process_by_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

```py
process = ReadWriteMemory.get_process_by_name(process_name="###########")
process.open()
```

Comment: You need to create an instance of the `ReadWriteMemory` class, and call the method on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

process = ReadWriteMemory().get_process_by_name(process_name="###########")
process.open()